# Find a polynomial $p(x)$ with degree lesser than or equal to $3$, with $p(1) = 2, p(2) = 3, p(4) = 5, p(6) = 7$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find a polynomial $p(x)$ with degree lesser than or equal to $3$, with $p(1) = 2, p(2) = 3, p(4) = 5, p(6) = 7$.

Also, prove that there is exactly **one** polynomial that satisfies the above criteria.

I've tried this using the *Lagrange interpolating formula*. But without much clarity.

EDIT 1: I think I've figured out a way, and I will post it answer soon...
EDIT 2: I cannot see why I got so many downvotes; I can't understand what should I do to make this question better...
Can somebody please suggest?

Comment: Why wouldn't a "naive" approach where you solved a system of 4 linear equations do the job?

Comment: Per the comment of @Deepak, exactly.  That is, set $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$.  You end up with 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns that may or may not be solvable.  As you *solve* the system, you will (presumably) simultaneously be *proving* that the solution (i.e. the solved values for $a,b,c,d$) is unique.

Comment: thanks, guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. solution:

We see that $g(x) =x+1$ works. Then polynomial $h(x) = p(x)-g(x)$ is of degree $3$ or less and has $4$ zeroes. That means that it is identical to $0$ which give us $p(x)$ is unique.

---

2. solution:

Write $p(x) =ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and write system: $$2 = p(1) =a+b+c+d$$ and so on and solve the system. You see that $a,b,c,d$ are uniqly determined.